# isomorphism between algebras of natural numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I have one problem with the algebra. I´d like to ask you if there exist some isomorphism between (N,+) and (N,*).

Comment: Hint: How many idempotents does each have?

Comment: Do you consider $\Bbb N$ to contain $0$?

Comment: Only one a that is number 1

Comment: Natural numbers without 0

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger That's why I chose the hint I did. It works in either case.

Comment: The hint of Tobias is enough to answer your question, but just so you know in general it is not hard to see that $(\mathbb{N}^*,\cdot)$ is a countable direct sum of copies of $(\mathbb{N},+)$ (this is actually the fundamental theorem of arithmetic).

Comment: Wait, i consider (N,⋅) and not (N∗,⋅)

Comment: As long as it is the same set in each case, my hint works. Otherwise, you need to edit the question.

Comment: OK I consider homomorphism f: N to N. Then I have f(1)=f(1*1)=f(1)*f(1) so then f(1)=1 and there exist only one homomorphism 1 to 1 ?

Comment: Why are you ignoring my hint?

Comment: And it is isomorphism yes ?

Comment: Why are you multiplying both places there? One of the structures has addition.

Comment: n=f(1+1+...+1)=f(1)*f(1)*...*f(1)=k*n where f(1)=k so then k=1 a f(1)=1 yes ?

Comment: I was not able to parse the last bit. But I don't really feel like continuing this if you are just going to continue ignoring my hints.

Comment: Ok I give it up ....

Comment: Can you help me more please ?

Comment: Did you even look at the hint I gave you?

Comment: Yes, of course, I find idempotent ... it is number 1 ... so I try to find homomorphism ...

Comment: No, the hint was to count the number of idempotents in both.

Comment: Oooh I´m sorry. in this case we have 2 of idempotents ... number 1 and 2

Comment: $2$ is definitely not an idempotent in either.

Comment: In the algebra (N,*) I have only 1, that number 1 agree ?

Comment: In algebra (N,+) there is no idempotent

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Ok, so if I consider f: (N,*) to (N,+) so there is no homomorphism becace there do not exist n element N that n=n+n yes ? The question is if exist homomorphism f: (N,+) to (N,*) yes ?

Comment: In the second case I have n=f(n)=f(1+...+1)=f(1)*....*f(1)=n*f(1) so then f(1)=1 so there exist only one homomorphism f:1 to 1 a so finally there is not isomorphism. Agree ?

Comment: Having different numbers of idempotents already ruled out there being an isomorphism. There are infinitely many homomorphisms from tghe additive to the multiplicative, as already mentioned in a previous comment by Captain Lama

Comment: Thanks, so to sum up,  there are infinitely many homomorphisms from the additive to the multiplicative but  there is no  homomorphisms from the multiplicative to the additive and so there is no isomorphism betweene this two algebras. Yes ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time.